# Dataflow and Bigtable dependency conflict

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bigtable

The error I'm getting:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

My pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
            <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-beam</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I assumed that the issue was coming from the two dependencies using different versions of the beam sdk, so I changed the `beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java` version to `2.11.0`, which uses the same beam sdk version. But I got the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the beam jar to be certain the DoFn class is contained in it? That would be my first check.

Comment: Looks like you might need the beam artifact ```beam-sdks-java-core```. Check that jar for the DoFn class.

Comment: I think Trey is right. You could refer to Beam's java quickstart for what's common Beam jars you should include: https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. I added `beam-sdks-java-core` to my dependencies and the error did not change. I also tried changing the versions of the beam dependencies to 2.11.0 (to match the beam versions used by the bigtable dependency) and the error also did not change. Any other ideas? =/

Answer (score 1):

How are you running the pipeline? I'm guessing that the issue is that the beam jars are not on your classpath. You either need to use the maven exec plugin to invoke your main() with all of the maven dependencies on the classpath or you need to create a fat jar using something like the maven shade plugin or the maven assembly plugin. Please see here for example of how to use the maven exec plugin to run a pipeline:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/a017a237fa8dae764451a658150190743c1b4127/java/dataflow-connector-examples/pom.xml#L146-L161